# Error in ConnectionString Keyword not supported: 'provider'

Tags: c#, mysql, connection, connection-string

I am using EntityConnectionStringBuilder for create ConnectionString to MySQL database but i got an error "Keyword not supported: 'provider'" i don't know why i getting this error

My Code

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder csb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb.ProviderConnectionString = "Server=Ip;User Id=user;Password=123456;database=dev pooling=false";
            csb.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
            return csb.ConnectionString;
```

pls help me solve this error and I using Entity Framwork

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon ";" in your connection string. I dont know if fixing that fixes the problem like so. The provider is blamed in your error message, because it is the immediate next property after the connection string in the `EntityConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
EntityConnectionStringBuilder csb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
            csb.ProviderConnectionString = "Server=Ip;User Id=user;Password=123456;database=dev;pooling=false";
            csb.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
            return csb.ConnectionString;
```

I would recommend using a separate `SQLConnectionStringBuilder`, and set the `Pooling` property in that like so:

```
string connectionString = "Server=Ip;User Id=user;Password=123456;database=dev";
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder scsb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
scsb.Pooling = true;

EntityConnectionStringBuilder csb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.ProviderConnectionString = scsb.ConnectionString; 
csb.Provider = "MySql.Data.MySqlClient";
return csb.ConnectionString;
```